# Recommended index on MySQL for a points system

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, indexing, mysql-workbench

I'm creating an appstore database system where I will be using a points system to show the points balance of users using the app. This points system will be updated using paypal (points are like micro-payments) to update the points a user has.

My quick question is relatively simple, what data type should I use to show the points in a table on MySQL workbench? (decimal, int, etc whatever is the best recommended).

Thanks.

*A quick update, the point system should reflect the users balance, but not necessarily show their points in a financial format (as this will be easier than having to use individual currency I assume).

Comment: A quick update, the point system should reflect the users balance, but not necessarily show their points in a financial format (as this will be easier than having to use individual currency I assume).

Comment: Apologies I didn't see the edit link before, thanks!

Comment: **You** have to decide whether the stored value is an INTEGER or a DECIMAL.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll need to use an INTEGER index, as the value is going to be a number regardless.